# not sure why this returns an infinite loop

Tags: c, logical-operators

I'm trying to count the number of 0's that occur in an array of 0's and 1's. If half of the array is 0, I keep it.  If not, I change it. I start counting on the 2nd digit (index 1) for convenience. I'm not concerned with index 0 and don't count it. I'm not sure why I'm getting an infinite loop with this.. could it be the equality in

```
 if (z == 4){
      g = 1;
    }
```

---

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(){
  int i, j, z, g;
  z = 0;
  int ar[9] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  g = 0;
  while(!g){
    for(i = 1; i < 9; i++){
      printf("%d", ar[i]);
      if (ar[i] == 0){
        z++;
      }
    }
    if (z == 4){
      g = 1;
    }
    else {
      for (i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        ar[i] = 0;
      }
      for (i = 5; i < 9; i++){
        ar[i] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("\n %d", z);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `else {` --> `else { z = 0;`

Comment: doesn't the else take care of this issue? if the else statement works it would be 4 ..

Comment: no, because if z != 4 you go into the for loops, but z is already > 4, so you'll never reach (g=1)

Comment: `z` must be reset to `0` before the next while-loop.

Comment: ah thanks for the helpful pointer @BLUEPIXY i'm too sleep deprived to notice that at first, was staring for an hour :(

Answer (score 4):

After first for loop the z value will be 8 so g value will never be 1.

Comment: answer with code that he is doing wrong would be more clear to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to re-initializate `z=0` every loop because you have a different array every loop. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /*Use <libname.h> instead of "libname.h"*/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i, j, z, g;
    z = 0;
    int ar[9] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    g = 0;
    while(!g){
        z=0; /*You must re-initializate the z value every loop*/
        for(i = 1; i < 9; i++){
            printf("%d", ar[i]);
            if (ar[i] == 0){
                z++;
            }
        }
        if (z == 4){
            g = 1;
        }else {
            for (i = 1; i < 5; i++){
                ar[i] = 0;
            }
            for (i = 5; i < 9; i++){
                ar[i] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
printf("\n %d", z);
return 0;
}
```

Hint: use indentation and try to re-write it better, the flow of the program is not easy to understand here

Answer (score 1):

All seems OK just use

```
if (z >= 4){
  g = 1;
}
```

You will get your expected result I think